# Python: play sound as input

Tags: python, linux, audio

Is it possible to play a wav/mp3/... file, so that the system thinks, its a microphone that plays the sound?

For example, I have this list of sounds:
 1.wav
 2.wav
 3.wav

Now I have a terminal, that lets me choose one of this sounds. Is it possible to let Python act like a microphone?